# How to push a private docker image to gitlab container registry in a local gitlab server

Tags: docker, gitlab

I'm running two machine with 2 local IP addresses (in a seperate system)

- On machine1, I install a local gitlab server with local IP address 10.2.3.105 (don't have public IP address)
- On machine2, I install gitlab-runner and setup my own docker image named "ansible:2.9.27" with local IP address 10.2.3.100

After registering successfully docker images with local gitlab server.

Could any body How to push my image to gitlab container registry in my local gitlab server with private IP address.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see container registry, it means that the container registry feature has not been enabled for your instance by your administrator or has been disabled in the project settings.

To fix this, the administrator must [enable the container registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#enable-the-container-registry).

Comment: I've just enabled container registry, I also created a user access token named CI_GITLAB_TOKEN, but I can't login to container registry with this command: "docker login $CI_REGISTRY -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_GITLAB_TOKEN

Comment: Note:  $CI_REGISTRY = registry.gitlap.com   $CI_REGISTRY_USER=root $CI_GITLAB_TOKEN=uaa1pe6CV7Zz7oDwTzyD

Comment: It always returns this response: "Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/": unauthorized: HTTP Basic: Access denied". So how can I login to Container registry?

Comment: If you have a self-hosted instance, you need to use _your_ container registry URL, not `registry.gitlab.com` @TRONGNGUYEN

Comment: You mean container registry URL is this link: "http://10.2.3.105/gitlab-instance-8cbc9e71/docker-ansible/container_registry" (as follow my own gitlab server and project)

Comment: @TRONGNGUYEN it's the host you configured when enabling the registry, per the documentation. You can also use `$CI_REGISTRY` if you configured container registry appropriately.

Comment: Now, I could resolve the container registry URL with my local gitlab server, but when I login with command "docker login". It has the error like this: "Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry.demogitlab.com/v2/": dial tcp 10.2.3.105:443: connect: connection refused". How can I connect to gitlab container registry with port 80 or link "http://registry.demogitlab.com"